# How are changes validated in gun?

Tags: database, gun

In the wiki of the gun repo on github, there is a section about "Security, Authentication, Authorization" ([Wiki Page](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/Security,-Authentication,-Authorization)).
It describes the problem of how to avoid someone making invalid changes to the data like spamming the database or erasing the enitre database, but it doesn't describe how the problem is solved in gun. So the question simply is:

how is it solved?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great question! We don't have a code demo up yet, but I'll answer your question once we do - it roughly involves adding a pre `gun.on('in', cb)` hook that rejects messages (doesn't `next()`) if the signatures don't validate If somebody is willing to sit down with me we can prototype it out together. In the meantime, here are some other useful resources: 1 minute explainer videos on cryptography http://gun.js.org/explainers/data/security.html , and an example implementation of user login auth: https://github.com/swifty/gun-p2p-auth .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains a lot. If I understand correctly I would install such a hook on a 'trusted' node in the network eg. my server or something, right? Is the signature of the hook documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm working on an example P2P crypto social network now (although it isn't a high priority), hopefully I'll have it out that I can show it to you - so for now, no. Sorry about that. But soon!

Comment: Thank you, no problem at all.

Comment: @marknadal any updates on this?

Comment: @marknadal any updates on this?